# Select marker located below a rectangle selection drawn by user over google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

code below includes appropriate comments for proper understanding. Please let me know if the question is not clear

My requirement is to get the information of all markers under a rectangle selection made by user over the map. (using control key + mouse down + mouse move event)

I have a list of markers to be plotted in the google map. In order to manipulate it later I have used Custom Overlays provided by the API. it works fine.

Now I need to allow user to draw a rectangle selection by pressing Control key + mouse down. When the mouse moves, a rectangle is drawn over the map and a check is done whether any marker lies below the rectangle drawn. This also works fine.

However If I scroll the map using mouse the values are wrongly calculated and not getting result. i.e the rectangle is not drawn properly.

My analysis is something wrong with the usage of PageX and PageY of mouse move event. Initially I used clientX and clientY, but to account scroll I used PageX and PageY.

What could be wrong here ? Kindly let me know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proto 1 displaying a list of cameras with custom markers.</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #rectangle {
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid #c1e0ff;
            z-index: 100000;
            visibility: hidden;
            background-color: #c1e0ff;
            opacity: 0.5
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBY_Jb6UGbhR1g9cM3uPGStdevUputZh5s"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        /* Need to listen for control key + mouse down + mouse move to draw a rectangle over google map and check for markers below the selection*/
        document.addEventListener('keydown', multipleCameraSelection);

        function multipleCameraSelection(e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey) {
                map.setOptions({
                    draggable: false
                });

                document.onmousedown = function(event) {

                    /*get div having ID of rectangle.This is created and added to the overlay image pane of map in the draw() function*/
                    var rectangleDiv = document.getElementById('rectangle');

                    /*get the co ordinates where mouse is clicked*/
                    var initialX = event.pageX;
                    var initialY = event.pageY;

                    rectangleDiv.style.left = initialX + 'px';
                    rectangleDiv.style.top = initialY + 'px';

                    document.onmousemove = function(event) {

                        /*on mouse move width and height of rectangle is calculated and set*/
                        var wid = Math.abs(event.pageX - initialX);
                        var hei = Math.abs(event.pageY - initialY);

                        rectangleDiv.style.width = wid + 'px';
                        rectangleDiv.style.height = hei + 'px';

                        rectangleDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';

                        if (event.pageX < initialX && event.pageY >= initialY) {
                            rectangleDiv.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
                        } else if (event.pageY <= initialY && event.pageX >= initialX) {

                            rectangleDiv.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';
                        } else if (event.pageY < initialY && event.pageX < initialX) {

                            rectangleDiv.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
                            rectangleDiv.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';
                        }

                    }

                    document.onmouseup = function(event) {
                        document.onmousedown = null;
                        document.onmousemove = null;
                        document.onmouseup = null;
                        rectangleDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';

                        /*get the current left , top value of element*/
                        var rectPos = getOffsetValues(rectangleDiv);


                        /*all markers have a name starting with cameraDiv. checking whether they lies between the rectangle drawn*/
                        $("div[id^='cameraDiv']").each(function(index, value) {

                            var elemToFind = value;

                            var elemToFindpos = getOffsetValues(elemToFind);

                            if ((((rectPos.topValue + rectangleDiv.offsetHeight) > elemToFindpos.topValue) && (rectPos.topValue < elemToFindpos.topValue || rectPos.topValue <= (elemToFindpos.topValue + elemToFind.offsetHeight))) &&
                                (((rectPos.leftValue + rectangleDiv.offsetWidth) > elemToFindpos.leftValue) && (rectPos.leftValue < elemToFindpos.leftValue || rectPos.leftValue <= (elemToFindpos.leftValue + elemToFind.offsetWidth)))) {

                                console.log(value);
                            }

                        })

                        map.setOptions({
                            draggable: true
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function getOffsetValues(elem) {
            var left = 0,
                top = 0;

            while (elem) {
                left += elem.offsetLeft;
                top += elem.offsetTop;
                elem = elem.offsetParent;
            }
            return {
                leftValue: left,
                topValue: top
            };

        }

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 12,
                center: {
                    lat: 8.5241,
                    lng: 76.9366
                }
            });

            overlay = new CameraLayer(map);
            //setMarkers(map);
        }

        var overlay;
        CameraLayer.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        function CameraLayer(map) {
            this.map_ = map;
            this.div_ = null;
            this.setMap(map);
            //window.alert('constructor called');
        }

        CameraLayer.prototype.onAdd = function() {
            var panes = this.getPanes();
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.style.position = 'absolute';
            div.id = 'myCustomdiv';
            this.div_ = div;

            panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div_);

        }

        CameraLayer.prototype.draw = function() {

            /*when a scroll happens replot the markers in correct pixel coordinates using methods exposed by map api*/
            while (this.div_.firstChild)
                this.div_.removeChild(this.div_.firstChild);

            var msgContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();

            for (i = 0; i < camerasToPlace.length; i++) {

                var lat = camerasToPlace[i];
                var lat1 = lat[1];
                var lng1 = lat[2];

                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng({
                    lat: lat1,
                    lng: lng1
                });

                var pixelPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(latLng);

                //msgContainer.appendChild()

                var div1 = document.createElement('div');
                div1.id = 'cameraDiv' + i;
                div1.style.position = 'absolute';

                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = 'camera.png';
                img.style.position = 'absolute';
                //img.style.width = '100%';
                //img.style.height = '100%';



                div1.style.left = pixelPosition.x + 'px';
                div1.style.top = pixelPosition.y + 'px';
                //
                div1.style.width = '32px';
                div1.style.height = '32px';

                div1.appendChild(img);

                msgContainer.appendChild(div1)


            }

            /*creating and appending a div to the overlay image , width and height calculated when the mouse move event happens , style applied above*/
            var rectDiv = document.createElement('div');
            rectDiv.id = 'rectangle';
            rectDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
            this.div_.appendChild(rectDiv);

            /*container holding marker data to plot in map with left and top values*/
            this.div_.appendChild(msgContainer);

        }


        /* a list holding the latitude and longitude values to be used in draw function to plot in map*/
        var camerasToPlace = [
            ['Camera1 located at TVM', 8.545394, 76.883503],
            ['Camera2 located at TVM', 8.7379, 76.7163],
            ['Camera3 located at TVM', 8.8932, 76.6141],
            ['Camera4 located at TVM', 8.7707, 76.8836],
            ['Camera5 located at TVM', 8.936906, 76.871831],
            ['Camera6 located at TVM', 8.485295, 76.916806]
        ];

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using selection of the wekpage; To acomplish your goals I would use click events inside the map.  Then you don't need to worry about pageX, pageY (which can be quite tricky)

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay your suggestion worked. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Emmanuel Delay, reworked on this using map events and its working
Here is the code for that, if it helps anyone. Please note we have to do control +  mouse down + mouse move to draw a selection. Also the div element holding marker have a predefined name appended to identify it later

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proto 1 displaying a list of cameras with custom markers.</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #rectangle {
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid #c1e0ff;
            z-index: 100000;
            visibility: hidden;
            background-color: #c1e0ff;
            opacity: 0.5
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBY_Jb6UGbhR1g9cM3uPGStdevUputZh5s"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var mapMouseMoveHandler;
        var mapMouseDownHandler;
        var mapMouseUpHandler;

        document.addEventListener('keydown', controlKeyDown);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', controlKeyUp);

        function controlKeyDown(e) {

            if (e.ctrlKey) {
                mapMouseDownHandler = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', cameraSelectionOnMouseDown);
            }
        }


        function controlKeyUp(e) {
            if (e.key == 'Control') {
                google.maps.event.removeListener(mapMouseDownHandler);
            }
        }

        function getElementOffsetValues(elem) {
            var left = 0,
                top = 0;

            while (elem) {
                left += elem.offsetLeft;
                top += elem.offsetTop;
                elem = elem.offsetParent;
            }
            return {
                leftValue: left,
                topValue: top
            };

        }

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 12,
                center: {
                    lat: 8.5241,
                    lng: 76.9366
                }
            });

            overlay = new CameraLayer(map);
            //setMarkers(map);
        }

        function cameraSelectionOnMouseDown(e) {

            map.setOptions({
                draggable: false
            });

            var rectangleDiv = document.getElementById('rectangle');
            var pixelPosition = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(e.latLng);
            var initialX = pixelPosition.x;
            var initialY = pixelPosition.y;

            rectangleDiv.style.left = initialX + 'px';
            rectangleDiv.style.top = initialY + 'px';

            mapMouseMoveHandler = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(e) {

                var newXY = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(e.latLng);
                var wid = Math.abs(newXY.x - initialX);
                var hei = Math.abs(newXY.y - initialY);

                rectangleDiv.style.width = wid + 'px';
                rectangleDiv.style.height = hei + 'px';
                rectangleDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';

                if (newXY.x < initialX && newXY.y >= initialY) {
                    rectangleDiv.style.left = newXY.x + 'px';
                } else if (newXY.y <= initialY && newXY.x >= initialX) {

                    rectangleDiv.style.top = newXY.y + 'px';
                } else if (newXY.y < initialY && newXY.x < initialX) {

                    rectangleDiv.style.left = newXY.x + 'px';
                    rectangleDiv.style.top = newXY.y + 'px';
                }
            })

            mapMouseUpHandler = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function(e) {

                google.maps.event.removeListener(mapMouseMoveHandler);
                google.maps.event.removeListener(mapMouseUpHandler);

                var rectPosition = getElementOffsetValues(rectangleDiv);

                $("div[id^='cameraDiv']").each(function(index, value) {

                    var elemToFind = value;

                    var elemToFindposition = getElementOffsetValues(elemToFind);

                    if ((((rectPosition.topValue + rectangleDiv.offsetHeight) > elemToFindposition.topValue) && (rectPosition.topValue < elemToFindposition.topValue || rectPosition.topValue <= (elemToFindposition.topValue + elemToFind.offsetHeight))) &&
                        (((rectPosition.leftValue + rectangleDiv.offsetWidth) > elemToFindposition.leftValue) && (rectPosition.leftValue < elemToFindposition.leftValue || rectPosition.leftValue <= (elemToFindposition.leftValue + elemToFind.offsetWidth)))) {

                        console.log(value);
                    }

                })

                rectangleDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                map.setOptions({
                    draggable: true
                });
            });

        }

        var overlay;
        CameraLayer.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        function CameraLayer(map) {
            this.map_ = map;
            this.div_ = null;
            this.setMap(map);
        }

        CameraLayer.prototype.onAdd = function() {
            var panes = this.getPanes();
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.style.position = 'absolute';
            div.id = 'myCustomdiv';
            this.div_ = div;

            panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div_);

        }

        CameraLayer.prototype.draw = function() {

            while (this.div_.firstChild)
                this.div_.removeChild(this.div_.firstChild);

            var msgContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();

            for (i = 0; i < camerasToPlace.length; i++) {

                var lat = camerasToPlace[i];
                var lat1 = lat[1];
                var lng1 = lat[2];

                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng({
                    lat: lat1,
                    lng: lng1
                });

                var pixelPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(latLng);


                var div1 = document.createElement('div');
                div1.id = 'cameraDiv' + i;
                div1.style.position = 'absolute';

                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = 'camera.png';
                img.style.position = 'absolute';
                //img.style.width = '100%';
                //img.style.height = '100%';



                div1.style.left = pixelPosition.x + 'px';
                div1.style.top = pixelPosition.y + 'px';
                //
                div1.style.width = '32px';
                div1.style.height = '32px';

                div1.appendChild(img);

                msgContainer.appendChild(div1)


            }

            var rectDiv = document.createElement('div');
            rectDiv.id = 'rectangle';
            rectDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
            this.div_.appendChild(rectDiv);

            this.div_.appendChild(msgContainer);

        }

        var camerasToPlace = [
            ['Camera1 located at TVM', 8.545394, 76.883503],
            ['Camera2 located at TVM', 8.7379, 76.7163],
            ['Camera3 located at TVM', 8.8932, 76.6141],
            ['Camera4 located at TVM', 8.7707, 76.8836],
            ['Camera5 located at TVM', 8.936906, 76.871831],
            ['Camera6 located at TVM', 8.485295, 76.916806]
        ];

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```